# Are Ubuntu TV questions off-topic?

Tags: support

The tile says it all. The questions which belong to Ubuntu TV should they be considered as off-topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Depends on the question

If the question can practically answered using available information, it is ontopic . Else it is offtopic(too localized)

I don't know whether ubuntu-tv developers subscribed to that tag

Comment: Else it's Too Localized*